# Is it possible to center an image inside a wrapper with an overflow hidden?

Tags: css, image, centering

I need my thumbnail to fill in the space of the container which is 100x100px. But I have some landscape images that I would like to have centered inside so they get cropped of left and right side. Is it possible to achieve this without using a background image.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey
}

.thumbnail {
  overflow: hidden
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/JYjBNP?editors=110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind about IE support, you can use `object-fit: cover;` property.

css:

```
.outer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.thumbnail {
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="outer">
        <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" />
        </div>
</div>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d0wvvdf8/1/

Comment: lovely! didn't know about that property

Answer (score 1):

Are your portrait images always going to be the same size, or will they be variable widths? If they're the same size, you can do this:

http://codepen.io/tinyglowstudio/pen/ojNVGj?editors=110

HTML:

```
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97100&w=300&h=100" alt="" />
```

I changed it to 300 and 100 for my own math. You can do the algebra yourself :)

CSS:

```
img
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
    clip: rect(0px 200px auto 100px);
    transform: translate(-100px);
```

This works in IE

Comment: The images are never the same size so setting image sizes is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the width from `width: auto` to `width: 100px` the image gets resized to fit inside the thumbnail. If that's what you want.

Comment: I checked @Ingvi 's codepen and came to the same solution.

Comment: The image will be stretched and out of proportions or the aspect ratio will not remain. It I set the height as a fixed size then I can not do the same with the width.

Comment: you updated your question to say that you want images cropped but centered, how about this?  http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/vNYaVx?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a new answer using JS to set our clipping amounts:

http://codepen.io/tinyglowstudio/pen/ojNVGj?editors=111

HTML:

```
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=450%C3%97250&w=450&h=250" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
img
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
```

JS

```
$(".thumbnail img").each(function() {
   var Height = 100 / $(this).height();
   var Width = $(this).width() * (100 / $(this).height());
   var trimAmount = (Width - 100) / 2;
   $(this).css({
       'transform' : 'translate(-' + trimAmount + 'px, 0)', 
       'clip' : 'rect(0 ' + (100 + trimAmount) + 'px 100px ' + trimAmount + 'px)'});
});
```